# How to convert this shell code string to an integer

Tags: python

I am working on an information security course and have an element of code that I need to understand:

```
"\x66\x68\xb0\xef". # PORT
```

My understanding is that this should translate to an integer value > 1024 but Im not sure how to calculate this.

I can see this string contains separated HEX values so tried printing the respective HEX values that are separated by \x and get the following:

```
>> print (int('66',16))
102
>>> print (int('68',16))
104
>>> print (int('b0',16))
176
>>> print (int('ef',16))
239
```

Obviously this gives me four separate values, so is not what I need, which is a single integer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is your friend. It packs integers into bytes and bytes into integers, if this is a big endian representation, then you should do:

```
import struct
as_int = struct.unpack('>I', the_str)[0]
```

And for little endian:

```
import struct
as_int = struct.unpack('<I', the_str)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack to an unsigned int with [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> import struct   
>>> struct.unpack('I',"\x66\x68\xb0\xef")[0]
4021315686
```